# Copiar CANVAS en formato imagen

Tags: html, angular, typescript, canvas

Tengo un diseño en CANVAS diseñado con la librería de `FabricJS`, por lo que requiero copiar el canvas y volverlo imagen pero conservando el CANVAS y la Imagen en la misma seccion de la pagina. ¿Cómo podría lograr lo que pretendo?

[image: Canvas]

**HTML**

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="400px" height="100px" style="border:solid;">

</canvas>
<img alt="Imagen del Canvas" id="img" width="11" height="12" src="noImg">
```

**ANGULAR/TPYESCRIPT**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.canvas = new fabric.Canvas('myCanvas', );
    this.canvas.add(new fabric.IText('Bayern Munchen'));
    fabric.Image.fromURL('https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-gunJY3CHi9E/WVDEnsgA7rI/AAAAAAABJzs/oJrbBdyKUToGoBS42ikY6YkWAFTqEGwZgCLcBGAs/s1600/FC%2BBayern%2BMunchen.png', (image) => {
      image.set({
        left: 50,
        top: 50,
      });

      this.canvas.add(image);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No entiendo porque pasas una imagen a un canvas y luego preguntas como pasarlo a imagen de nuevo (ya tienes la URL de la imagen) pero eh aquí el código (javascript) para eso

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var img    = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
document["img"].src = img;
// o también puedes hacerlo así
//document.getElementById('img').src = img;
//Como alternativa puedes crear un objeto Image sin tenerlo en el documento html
var imgObject = new Image();
imgObject.src = img;
```

Comment: Hola @LPZadkiel, mira la imagen que hay en esa seccion que haces referencias es la del logo del equipo, en mi caso pretendo que se pueda manejar cualquier imagen que esté almacenada en una URL de terceros y no directamente en mi sitio. Y me refiero es a que lo que hay contenido en el canvas se pueda pasar o copiar a un formato imagen para posteriormente manipularla como pretendo.