# ¿Cómo convertir una gráfica chartJS a PNG?

Tags: php, base64, img, chart.js

tengo una gráfica de barras generada con chartJS y deseo convertirla a PNG mediante base64, para después pasar esa imagen a Mpdf.
He buscado y avanzado un poco, pero no hay mucha información al respecto y parecer algo estoy haciendo mal porque sí genera el archivo .PNG, pero al querer abrirlo no se ve nada y tira el mensaje "parece que el formato de este archivo no es compatible".

Comparto el código a continuación.

```
//omití la consulta mysql 
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
     <head>
      <title>Bar Chart</title>
      <script src="js/chartJS/Chart.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
     </head>
     <body>
      <div style="width: 50%">
       <canvas id="canvas" height="450" width="600"></canvas>
      </div>
    
    
     <script>
    
     var barChartData = {
      labels : ['ASISTENCIAS', 'FALTAS', 'PERMISOS', 'RETARDOS'],
      datasets : [
       {
        fillColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
        strokeColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.8)",
        highlightFill : "rgba(151,187,205,0.75)",
        highlightStroke : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        data : [
      <?php
      $sql= "select count(Asistencia), pasalista.asistencia from pasalista inner join alumnos where pasalista.A_Ncontrol=alumnos.A_Ncontrol and alumnos.A_grado='1' and alumnos.A_grupo='a' group by Asistencia";
      $result = mysqli_query($cone,$sql);?>
      <?php while ($registros = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){?> 
        <?php echo $registros["count(Asistencia)"]?>,<?php } ?>
      ]
       }
      ]
     };
     window.onload = function(){
      var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
      window.myBar = new Chart(ctx).Bar(barChartData, {
       responsive : true
      });
     };
     </script>
     <form method="POST" action="imagen.php" name="form" id="form">
      <input type="hidden" name="base64" id="base64"/>
      <button type="submit">
        Guardar imagen
      </button>
    </form>
    
    <script>
    
       // on the submit event, generate a image from the canvas and save the data in the textarea
       document.getElementById('form').addEventListener("submit",function(){
          var image = ctx.toDataURL(); // data:image/png....
          document.getElementById('base64').value = image;
       },false);
    
    </script>
     </body>
    </html>
```

y tengo un archivo que se llama imagen.php
con lo siguiente:

```
<?php

$img = $_POST['base64'];
$img2 = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
$fileData = base64_decode($img2);
$fileName = uniqid().'.png';
file_put_contents($fileName, $fileData);
header("Location: Nbarra.php")
?>
```

Comment: La gráfica se genera en un _canvas_, por lo que esto te puede servir: [Copiar CANVAS en formato imagen](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/177941/copiar-canvas-en-formato-imagen)

Comment: Ok lo checare gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gracias a la sugerencia que compartió [triby], obtuve el fundamento de lo que quería hacer, a continuación les comparto mi resultado.
NOTA: el objetivo final es utilizarlo para imprimir un reporte pdf con mPDF (pero aun no lo he logrado, cuando lo haga actualizaré esta respuesta) sin embargo, a continuación les comparto lo siguiente (funciona)
un archivo NG.php que genera una gráfica de barras canva la cual convierto a png mediante el metodo toDataURL envío el valor mediante POST y lo capturo en reportePDF.php para convertirlo en imagen. espero que le sirva a alguien.

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Bar Chart</title>
        <script src="js/chartJS/Chart.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="width: 50%">
            <canvas id="canvas" height="450" width="600"></canvas>
        </div>
        <form method="POST" action="reportePDF.php" name="form" id="form">
      <input type="hidden" name="base64" id="base64"/>
      <button type="submit" id="sBtn">
        PDF imagen
      </button>
    </form>


    <script>
    var randomScalingFactor = function(){ return Math.round(Math.random()*100)};

    var barChartData = {
        labels : ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July"],
        datasets : [
            {
                fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
                strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)",
                highlightFill: "rgba(220,220,220,0.75)",
                highlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                data : [randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor()]
            },
            {
                fillColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
                strokeColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.8)",
                highlightFill : "rgba(151,187,205,0.75)",
                highlightStroke : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                data : [randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor()]
            }
        ]

    }
    window.onload = function(){
        var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
        window.myBar = new Chart(ctx).Bar(barChartData, {
            responsive : true
        });
    }

    </script>
<script>
    sBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
var ncanva = document.getElementById("canvas");
var img = ncanva.toDataURL("image/png");
 document.getElementById('base64').value = img;
//document["img"].src = img;
// o también puedes hacerlo así
//document.getElementById('img').src = img;
//Como alternativa puedes crear un objeto Image sin tenerlo en el documento html
//var imgObject = new Image();
//imgObject.src = img;
});
</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

el sigueinte es reportePDF.php (por ahora solo es la imagen)

```
  <?php
$img = $_POST['base64'];
?>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div>
<img alt="Imagen del Canvas" id="img" name ="img" height="450" width="600" src="">
</div>
<div id="resultado"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var imgn ='<?php echo $img;?>'
    document.getElementById('img').src = imgn;
  </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

ACTUALIZACION: ASÍ QUEDA CON Mpdf.

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
$img = $_POST['base64'];
  $html= '
<table align="center">
      <tr>
              <td colspan="2"><H4><center>INSTITUTO ESTATAL DE EDUCACÓN PÚBLICA</center></H4></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><img src="img/EST.png" width="80px" height="80px"></td>
            <td><h3>ESCUELA SECUNDARIA TÉCNICA #</h3></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="center" colspan="2"><h3>CLAVE: 000000</h3></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
             <td align="center"><h3> REGIÓN: </h3></td>
              <td align="center"><h3> ZONA ESCOLAR: 000</h3></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td></td>
            </tr>
              <tr>
              <td align="center" colspan="2"><h3>GRAFICA GENERAL DE ASISTENCIA POR GRUPO </h3></td>
            </tr>
             <div>
<img alt="Imagen del Canvas" id="img" name ="img" height="450" width="600" src='.$img.'>
</div>';   
$html .= '</table>'; ?>
<?php
  $mpdf= new \Mpdf\Mpdf([]);
  $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
  $mpdf->Output();
?>
```